# overcomplete set of boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I have the following coupled differential equations-

$\frac{dp}{dt}=-\sin x+c\left(t\right)$

and $\frac{dx}{dt}= p$

but I don't know what is $c(t)$. 
I have an over-complete set of boundary conditions as follows- $x(t=0)=0$,  $\dot x(t=0)=0$  and  $\dot x(T)=0$  where $T$ is the time such that $x(T) = 2\pi$.

I need to choose $c(t)$ such that I can satisfy the above boundary conditions where $c(t)$, for example, can be a sequence of square pulses $c(t_j)$ over time-steps $t_j$ spread from $t=0$ to $t=2\pi$.

I could do an optimization of $c(t)$ which minimizes a function of $x_i,x_f,p_i,p_f$ which are initial and final positions and momenta such that the boundary conditions end up being satisfied for the whole period- $0$ to $2\pi$.

But can I do this in Mathematica in a more straightforward manner before I embark on the seemingly more complicated optimization procedure?

Comment: Can you share related literature to the odes?

Comment: @MMM this is actually mentioned in the literature as the 'tilted washboard potential'. I have written the equations of motion for this potential in the question but the difference is that I have made a constant $c$ into a time-dependent function $c(t)$